# Windows 10 "Start Menu" Settings missing

Tags: windows-10

Just upgraded another machine to Windows 10. My "Task bar and start menu settings" dialog is missing the "Start Menu" tab

(right click an empty area of the task bar, select "properties", brings up a dialog that usually includes tabs for Taskbar, Navigation, Start Menu and Toolbars. All there, all nifty except the "Start Menu" tab missing.

I've used this before on another computer, see also this pic:

[image]

Any idea what could cause this? I want to re-enable the full screen start menu (yeah, laugh at me all you like)

Comment: I think this was removed since the windows 10 threshold 2 update.

Comment: @LPChip: that might be the reason, this system is "late" in the upgrade process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the Start Menu settings by going to **Settings > Personalization > Start** and enable the **Use Start full screen** option.

There you will also find some familiar settings such as **Show most used apps** and **Show recently opened items** as well as an option to choose which items appear on start menu (e.g. Documents, Downloads, Settings, Network, etc).

Comment: Right, so Micrsooft has moved the setting. Not the first time they did it... :( Good answer though. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate tablet mode from Settings or Action Center (Windows + A) to use full screen start menu.

[image]

Comment: care to explain negative vote ?